# Single line for loop over iterator with an "if" filter?

Tags: python, loops

I have a simple `for` loop followed by a simple `if` statement:

```
for airport in airports:
    if airport.is_important:
```

and I was wondering if I can write this as a single line somehow.

Yes, I can do this:

```
for airport in (airport for airport in airports if airport.is_important):
```

but it reads so silly and redundant (`for airport in airport for airport in airports...`).

Is there a better way?

Comment: If you don't like having so many "airport"s in one line, swap three of them for a single character: `for airport in (x for x in airports if x.is_important):`

Comment: I wonder why Python doesn't have `for airport in airports if airport.is_important:`, it seems useful and clear.

Comment: You could also use `if not airport.is_important: continue`, to avoid indentation. But I like the accepted answer better, so I don't really know why I wrote this comment.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

No, there is no shorter way. Usually, you will even break it into two lines :

```
important_airports = (airport for airport in airports if airport.is_important)
for airport in important_airports:
    # do stuff
```

This is more flexible, easier to read and still don't consume much memory.

Comment: +1: Just write what you mean.  1-liner Code Golf is not a good practice.

Comment: Thank you - I really like this answer. While not a one liner, it 'captures the spirit' of the one liner in that there is a single indentation (am I allowed to say I hate indentations while still loving Python???).  
No need for extra imports and by using a proper variable name the second line is perfectly readable (who cares how I implemented 'important airports').  
This is my answer.  
Thanks again for the prompt reply!

Comment: @TalWeiss Of course you are allowed to hate indentations, I do too!

Answer (score 46):

You could do:

```
for airport in filter(lambda x: x.is_important, airports):
    # do stuff...
```

Comment: Depending on the size of your list, or rather the number of important airports, I think this is the best way. Its easy to read, once you've figured out `lambda`.

Comment: Since Python 2.4 (circa 2002) you can use a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and write `for airport in (airport for airport in airports if airport.is_important):` which makes using `filter()` for this purpose somewhat obsolete.

Answer (score 26):

I'd use a negative guard on the loop. It's readable, and doesn't introduce an extra level of indentation.

```
for airport in airports:
    if not airport.is_important: continue
    <body of loop>
```

Answer (score 4):

Mabe this, but it's more or less the same verbose...

```
import itertools

for airport in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x.is_important, airports):
    ...
```

Comment: Yes this is the best I could think of too.

Comment: @tusbar so what? the op is asking for more readable alternatives, not more efficient ones... and the difference is negligible (~ +-20%), if we'd care about that margins we would be programming in C, not in Python :-p

Comment: Actually, thank you for that @tusbar! I didn't ask for it but it is very informative (as someone who often optimizes code) and @fortran: these small differences add up very quickly in a big project. I added the answer I liked most to the snippet and it is actually faster!: http://codepad.org/CN5jsYhX

Answer (score 2):

This is a design philosophy of python.  If it takes you too many words to put it on one line, it should be broken into a few lines to help the person who comes after you.  List and generator expressions are more for transforming iterables in-place -- making more readable forms of `map` and `filter`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to some of the other filter versions:

```
from operator import attrgetter as attr
for airport in filter(attr('is_important'), airports):
    ...
```

This has the advantages of being pretty concise and also letting you use dot notation attr('first_class.is_full').

You could also put something like that (or a version using a list comprehension) into a utility function like filter_by_attr. Then you could do:

```
for airport in filter_by_attr(airports, 'is_important'):
    ...
```

I still think e-satis is right to put it in a new variable no matter the method you use, though. It is just clearer that way, especially if the use doesn't exactly match the name of the attribute in question (or the the criteria is more complex).

My only note on that would be that if you find yourself using this in several places, perhaps you should make airports a special collection with 'important_airports' being a @property which returns the filtered collection. Or some sort other abstraction to hide away the filtering (like a service call).

Answer (score 2):

I found the usage of the filter & lambda to be the easiest in a single line.

```
for filtered_airport in filter(lambda airport: airport.is_important, airports)):
    print(filtered_airport.some_property)
```

If you wish to return a list from output of this filter object you can do something like this.

```
filtered_airport_list = list(filter(lambda airport: airport.is_important, airports)))
```

Answer (score 0):

While in most cases I would just prefer to put an if statement inside the loop, there are some cases where something like this can be concise and readable.

```
def process_important_airport(airport):
    print(f"{airport.name} is really important!")
    
[process_important_airport(airport) for airport in airports if airport.is_important]
```

Answer (score -2):

Using list comprehension (only if airports is a list of objects):

```
for airport in [a for a in airports if a.is_important]:
```

Comment: this is completely wrong, it doesn't do what the OP is asking for, it iterates over the boolean values... basically, it's a map, not a filter!

Comment: It will iterate over a list of bools.

Comment: @rogeriopvl: your corrected version would then be a less efficient copy of the code the OP started with (and wanted an alternative for).

Comment: @rogeriopvl now you have the same version as the op, only with a list comprehension instead of an iterator expression

Comment: well, the op asked for a one liner