# How do I extract a particular section from textfile in python3

Tags: python-3.x

This is my python file

```
path = '/my/file/list.txt'
with open(path,'rt') as file:
    print("step 1")
    collected_lines = []
    started = False
    for line in file:   
        for n in range(1, 10):
            if line.startswith('PLAY NO.{}'.format(n)):
                started = True
                print("started at line {}".format(line[0]))
                continue
            if started:
                collected_lines.append(line)        
            if started and line == 'PLAY NO.{}'.format(n+1):
                print("end at line {}".format(line[0]))
                break           
            print(collected_lines.append(line))
```

This is my code..
OUTPUT:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

Now I want the lines starting from play No2 to play No3.... But I am getting None.. Please any suggestions... I am using Python 3.5

Sorry this is the first time asking question on this site..
My file looks like this..

textfile.txt

```
Hello and Welcome This is the list of plays being performed here
              PLAY NO. 1
 1. adknjkd
 2. skdi
 3. ljdij

              PLAY NO. 2
 1. hsnfhkjdnckj
 2. sjndkjhnd  and so on
```

Comment: What lines?  You show no lines.

Comment: We need an example of the file

Comment: I would recommend filter the lines you want to. Have a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401785/in-python-can-i-single-line-a-for-loop-over-iterator-with-an-if-filter that might give you a hint on how to do that in a convenience way. Furthermore I would recommend to use RegEx to filter that lines like `None != re.match("^No[0-9][^0-9]", line)`

Comment: You write: `"Now I want the lines starting from play No2 to play No3.."`, but in the file there is no play No3 ...

Comment: It's not my opinion, but it does make sense to me: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258004/should-thank-you-comments-be-flagged . The better way to say "thank you" is to accept the answer and upvote it (your upvote doesn't count yet, but later if you have more than 15 reps). You accept an answer by clicking on `"v"` so that it turns green. It's a good habit here on stackoverflow not to forget to accept an answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path = 'list.txt'
collected_lines = []
with open(path,'rt') as file:
    print("step 1")
    started = False
    lineNo  = 0
    for line in file:   
        lineNo += 1
        for n in range(1, 10):
            # print('PLAY NO. {}'.format(n))
            if started and line.lstrip().startswith('PLAY NO. {}'.format(n)):
                print("### end     at line {}".format(lineNo))
                started = False
                break           
            if line.lstrip().startswith('PLAY NO. {}'.format(n)):
                started = True
                print("### started at line {}".format(lineNo))
                break
        if started:
            collected_lines.append(line)

print("collected_lines: \n\n", *[ item for item in collected_lines ])
```

gives:

```
step 1
### started at line 2
### end     at line 7
collected_lines: 

               PLAY NO. 1
  1. adknjkd
  2. skdi
  3. ljdij
```

NOTES about fixed issues:

1. used `.lstrip()` in order to make `.startswith()` working as expected
2. added a space between `NO.` and `{}` in `startswith('PLAY NO. {}'.format(n)` so that the if condition can find the line
3. rearranged the order of `if`s in order to avoid that the end line is considered found at the start line
4. added `started = False` to the loop to stop collecting the lines.

The problem with the leading spaces was already enough to prevent the code from finding the line. Fixing this alone wouldn't fix the problem because of the missing space in the `format` string, so both issues had to be fixed to make the code work as expected. And so on ... see NOTES above.

Comment: you can replace `    for line in file:   
        lineNo += 1` with `for lineNo, line in enumerate(file):`

Comment: and how does this distinguish between play 1 and 2?

Comment: @MaartenFabré `and how does this distinguish between play 1 and 2?` It doesn't but ... printing `None` is away and the code is as similar as possible to OPs code. If you want play 2 you can change `for n in range(1,10)` to `for n in range(2,3)`. I fear that the code in your answer is too far away from the OPs, so that it makes it very hard for the OP to understand how and why it works (the reason I have limited my changes to the code to a minimum in order to get it to work).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dict with as labels the play number and as items a list with the lines about the play you can use a `defaultdict`

## Defining the text

```
text = """Hello and Welcome This is the list of plays being performed here
              PLAY NO. 1
 1. adknjkd
 2. skdi
 3. ljdij

              PLAY NO. 2
 1. hsnfhkjdnckj
 2. sjndkjhnd  and so on"""
```

## Defining the regular expression

```
regex = re.compile('^\s*PLAY NO. (\d+)$')
```

## Parsing the lines

```
label = None  # no play to start with
recorded_lines = defaultdict(list)

for line_no, line in enumerate(StringIO(text)):
# In the real code replace the 'StringIO(text)' with 'file'
    try:
        play_no = int(regex.findall(line)[0])
        # If this regex does not match, it will throw an IndexError 
        # The code underneath is only executed when a new play starts
        if label:  # if there is no play underway, there can be no ending
            print('PLAY NO. %i ended at line number %i' % (label, line_no-1))
        label = play_no
        print('PLAY NO. %i started at line number %i' % (play_no, line_no))
    except IndexError:
        # no new play started
        if label and line.strip():
            recorded_lines[play_no].append(line.strip())
    print(line_no, line)
print(recorded_lines)
```

yields

```
defaultdict(list,
            {1: [(2, '1. adknjkd'), (3, '2. skdi'), (4, '3. ljdij')],
             2: [(7, '1. hsnfhkjdnckj'), (8, '2. sjndkjhnd  and so on')]})
```

and this output on the `stout`:

```
0 Hello and Welcome This is the list of plays being performed here

PLAY NO. 1 started at line number 1
1               PLAY NO. 1

2  1. adknjkd

3  2. skdi

4  3. ljdij

5 

PLAY NO. 1 ended at line number 5
PLAY NO. 2 started at line number 6
6               PLAY NO. 2

7  1. hsnfhkjdnckj

8  2. sjndkjhnd  and so on
```

Comment: in python, Try/except is an acceptable [way](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) and should not be avoided at all costs. Used correctly it can give some really elegant code

Comment: This regular expression is a very simple one and might be a good introduction to them for newcomers. In this case, when you want to get the play number, a `regulr expression` is way easier, correct or readable than the `for`-loop in the original code

Comment: Thanks for your feedback (y) :) . Now I know you have read my comment I will delete it as it is of no use for future visitors here.