# Is there a shorter way to initialize this loop?

Tags: python

Is there a shorter way to initialize this loop?
It feels like typing "val" four times for such a simple statement might not be the fastest way to do it.

(The example is a random code for explaining my point, the actual loop content would be much more complex.)

```
values=[4,8,0,1,5,8,3]
for val in [val for val in values if val!=1]:
    print(val)
```

Comment: How about `for val in values: if val != 1: print(val)`? Too readable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single line for loop over iterator with an "if" filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401785/single-line-for-loop-over-iterator-with-an-if-filter)

Comment: that was my first option, but you gotta type the for-loop and the if-condition in different lines or python would raise a SyntaxError, and as I'm using this kind of logic a lot, I was wondering if there's a simple one-line solution

Comment: @StellarStreams If the code is simple than an extra line for the if condition won't kill you and it is very readable. *Readability counts* if the code is more complex you'll need to do the logic over several lines anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generator expression (no need to create yet another list to iterate over) and [the `filter()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) (creates an iterator) come to mind:

```
values = [4,8,0,1,5,8,3]

# generator expression instead of list expressen - is more efficient
for val in (val for val in values if val != 1):
    print(val)

# filter the list  - creates an iterator
for val in filter(lambda x:x != 1, values):
    print (val)
```

Output:

```
4
8
0
5
8
3
```

Comment: this is like shaving a cat using a chainsaw. very messy

Comment: @andrew Only if you touch the skin of the cat. Which one of both do you deem messy? I would not lable any of both as such ... with a more complex function to test I would create a function for that and use it in either one. Adding an if statement inside the loop is also a possibility but you already suggested that.

Comment: Both. Forever and a day I can glance over and read code that does loop, next line if condition, followed by some action without rereading. I'd have to take a second to read your code which defeats the purpose. We both know we'd do loop, next line if for the simple version anyway so its a moot point (I hope)